# missing ) in parenthetical

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm modifying BSN's Autosuggest script so it will work with codeigniter, the only proble is I cant seem to figure out why it displays "missing ) in parenthetical" says the problem is around `else`

```
_b.AutoSuggest.prototype.setSuggestions = function (req, input) {
    if (input != this.fld.value) return false;
    this.aSug = [];
    if (this.oP.json) {
        var jsondata = eval('(' + req.responseText + ')');
        for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.results.length; i++) {
            this.aSug.push({
                'id': jsondata.results[i].id,
                'value': jsondata.results[i].value,
                'info': jsondata.results[i].info
            });
        }
    } else {
        var xml = req.responseXML;
        // traverse xml
        //
        var results = xml.getElementsByTagName('results')[0].childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            if (results[i].hasChildNodes()) this.aSug.push({
                'id': results[i].getAttribute('id'),
                'value': results[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
                'info': results[i].getAttribute('info')
            });
        }
    }
    this.idAs = "as_" + this.fld.id;
    this.createList(this.aSug);
};
```

Any help would be appreciated, i'm not very good at JS

Comment: `eval` == **evil**.

Comment: Make sure you debug, like alerting the code to be `eval`ed.

Comment: @Jacob: `eval` is perfectly fine in the proper situation. There's no need to sound the evil alarm every time it appears in a piece of code.

Comment: It's possible the code that is returned has a misplaced ')'. I discovered in my travels that jQuery has a JSON parser. You should totally use that since it will give you syntax errors in your JSON. jQuery.parseJSON

Comment: `var jsondata = eval('(' + req.responseText + ')');` has a syntax error so its telling me....

Comment: Its probably because youre "missing ) in parenthetical"... like it says.

Comment: Do you mean that its missing the ) before `var jsondata = eval('(' + req.responseText + ')');`?

Comment: The code above seems ok. So the problem must be what `eval` is evaluating. In case, use Firefox + Firebug to debug. Will be easier :-) Btw are the '(' and ')' necessary?

Comment: What is the value of `req.responseText`? That's where the issue is.

Comment: @patrick but this is a perfect example of when you should not use it. You should use `JSON.parse` or something instead.

Comment: Value of `req.responseText` is `<li>admin</li><li>all</li>`

Comment: @MatrixFrog: I'd rather see JSON methods used too, but unless we know the data is insecure, we can't really say if this is an example of when to not use it. I haven't tested, but I'd bet that `eval` is faster than `JSON.parse` too.

Comment: If it's coming from an HTTP request (which it appears to be) then there's always a risk it could be insecure. Yes, eval is not **always** evil but in this case, you should definitely use JSON methods, even if it is a little slower.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: But where's the risk if the request is to your own server, and you control the data?

Comment: @patrick I've been working on a Firefox addon for a while, and in that case, the risks are greater. I guess in this case it's not so bad. It's still a good habit to get in to avoid `eval` at all costs, especially for someone that's still sort of a beginner. But you're right that just saying "eval is evil" over and over doesn't necessarily make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the server is invalid. Look at the responseText that is being returned with either [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getFirebug.com). It is most likely something being injected into the response that should not be there.

Also if you are using jQuery, change the code to use their ajax methods.